'TIBCO.Rendezvous.netmodule' cannot be loaded because only single file assemblies are supported. (0x8013101E)
Now, I have a netcore web app and I create a new plugin which will refer TIBCO.Rendezvous.dll. However, file named TIBCO.Rendezvous.dll contain TIBCO.Rendezvous.netmodule, and I encounter follow error:

System.IO.FileLoadException:“Could not load file or assembly 'TIBCO.Rendezvous.netmodule'. The module cannot be loaded because only single file assemblies are supported. (0x8013101E)”

1.I try add reference named TIBCO.Rendezvous.dll
2. I try using command 'gacutil.exe' to global load .
3. I expect who solve this problem.

As far as I know, .NET versions above 4.8.1 no longer support multifile assemblies, so you would need a new module from Tibco that supports the new .NET versions.  E.g.:

In .NET and .NET Framework, you can build an assembly from one or more
source code files. In .NET Framework, assemblies can contain one or
more modules. This way, larger projects can be planned so that several
developers can work on separate source code files or modules, which
are combined to create a single assembly. For more information about
modules, see How to: Build a multifile assembly.


The latest version of TIBCO Rendezvous (8.7) supports .NET 6.
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/rendezvous/8.7.0/TIB_rv_8.7.0_relnotes.pdf?id=1
